# Как убрать down/open из url (движок Даннео)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Здравствуйте!

У меня так: http://mysite.ru/down/open/article.html как сделать так: http://mysite.ru/article.html
У меня движок Даннео.

Это возможно. Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule !^down/open/ down/open/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: спасибо, но не помогает